# Checking a value initially from an array in radio buttons Angular typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, radio-button, angular9

I need to check the first value from my array which I get from a get request through an api
Following is my html

```
 <div class="row" class="select-options" *ngFor="let options of paymentOptions;let idx = index">
            <input  type="radio"
                   formControlName="paymentOption"
                   [value]="options"
                   [checked]="idx==0"
                   (change)="onSelectChange(options)"/>
            {{options}}
          </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi, init or set to the formControl "paymentOption" with the value of first v alue in array. And remove the attribute [checked] in template.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ReactiveForms.

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gbn2uy

You need to create a form group and you can set your initial/default value there, like this:

```
this.form = fb.group({
  paymentOption: [this.paymentOptions[0]]
});
```

So you do not need the `checked` property on the input itself.